# Join two tables with many to many relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have two tables with common columns ControlNo, QuoteID and PolicyNumber. in a In a table Losses, column "PaidLosses" also need to be broke down by Coverages like in a table Coverages?
Is any way I can join somehow those tables in order to break down PaidLosses by Coverages?[image]

Comment: which one of those ControlNo, QuoteID and PolicyNumber is the primary key? can you show the constraint between the tables?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding an example of the results you are looking for would be helpful here.

Comment: Those two tables populated by complex stored procedures that not documented and didnt created by me. QuoteID comes from a table Quotes with Primary Key QuoteGuid. I can bring that column in a table if need to

Comment: @Oleg it's not a problem to join to many to many tables but it's important to know what is the relation between those tables. see here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190742(v=sql.105).aspx how you can see the relation.

Comment: Each PolicyNumber has a WrittenPremium broken down by coverage. 
Some policies experiencing losses during policy life. Those losses are in another table, but not broken down by coverage.  So is any way if PolicyNumber has losses, then to figure out what coverage this loss related to.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused, but I think you want to group the items from your tbl losses by coverage? if that is the case I would use a groupby like and count to display the number of coverage's from the losses table:

```
select
quoteID
,a.controlNo
,AccidentYear
,AccidentMonth,PolicyNumber
,paidLosses
,count(b.coverage)
from tablLosses a
join coverage b
on a.controlNo = b.controlNo
group by Coverage
```

it should give you a count for each coverage.